# Web3j - Why does my contract's method have a BigInteger param generated by the Java Wrapper? What is it for?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3-java

I'm using the Web3j cli to generate a Java Wrapper for my ethereum smart contract.

```
function withdraw() external payable {
        address _caller = msg.sender;
        uint256 _userBalance = recipientBalances[_caller];

        if (isExpired() && _userBalance > 0) {
            uint256 _contractBalance = address(this).balance;
            recipientBalances[_caller] = 0;
            address payable _recipient = payable(_caller);
            if (_contractBalance > _userBalance) {
                _recipient.transfer(etherToWei(_userBalance));
            }
        }
    }
```

Upon generation it generates a method that accepts a `BigInteger` param, but my solidity contract for that method does not accept any params.

```
public RemoteFunctionCall<TransactionReceipt> withdraw(BigInteger weiValue) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                FUNC_WITHDRAW,
                Arrays.<Type>asList(),
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function, weiValue);
}
```

This does not occur for any of my other generated `Void` return type functions.

What is the `BigInteger` param used for?

Comment: looks like its a tokenId. can you show your `withdraw` method in the contract?

Comment: The withdraw method for the contract is already posted